# ObjectAnimator

Tags: android

Добрый вечер,

Изучаю Android-примеры, приведенные в SDK. Пытаюсь понять код примера из ApiDemos BouncingBalls.

Вопрос возник насчет строчки 
    ValueAnimator colorAnim = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(this, "backgroundColor", RED, BLUE);

параметры функции `ofInt(Object, // Объект, свойство которого анимируем
String  // свойство, int // меняем свойство от доб int);`

Так вот откуда мы берем свойства, к которым применяется анимация?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ищите обработчик `onAnimationUpdate()`, там получают значение через `getAnimatedValue()` после чего там же меняют реальное свойство анимируемого объекта. Т.е. название свойства может быть любым, как вам понравится, просто свойств может быть несколько (как заложите логику), важно чтоб вы умели определить вычисленное значение для конкретного свойства.

Подробнее [тут](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html#listeners).

Comment: буду читать